# Is it bad to murder the witch with the cottage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I accidentally stole an iron dagger from Anise's Cabin in her cottage near Riverwood and then I had to fight her and kill her. Are there any quests I may have missed out on?

Comment: Could you please post the name of the character, or it is a "Generic Witch". And, the  name of the city isnt Riverdale?

Comment: The name of the location is important as well. Most, if not all places in Skyrim are named. I would assume this cottage has a location marker?

Comment: And being "bad" about murdering NPC's on Skyrim is just a matter of point of view ;). I have also "removed" some npcs from the game and i couldn't care less about what kind of quest they will not give me...MUAHAHA

Answer (score 3):

Anise's Cabin is not used in any quest lines that I, or [this page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Anise%27s_Cabin) are aware of. There's a letter to Anise, an Alchemy skill book, an Alchemy Lab and an Arcane Enchanter in the basement, a bed and a garden. That's it. No quests reference it, everything in the house is considered stolen if you take it. Just an oddball little hut in the middle of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you go in her secret annex at the back of her house and come out, she will attack you. She has no pourpose, she is just a random encounter.